# Spring example of Accessing Data with MongoDB.. How do I tell it MongoDB server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mongo

I am looking at the Spring Boot example of Accessing Data with MongoDB from

http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

Can someone please tell me how to setup the MongoDB server IP or name.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the [Connecting to a MongoDB](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connecting-to-mongodb) section of the Spring Boot reference guide.

If your question is about installing MongoDB please see the [installation guides](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/).

Comment: He to link done work...mcao you please point me to some examples.. I just need to change the server of the database

Comment: I've fixed the link. Sorry about that!

Comment: maybe you can help... I added the following line to 

@PropertySource("classpath:/app-config.properties")

To Application.java and added app-config.properties to src/resources but
I am getting this error

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
[app-config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot why don't you use the default files as indicated in the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)?

Comment: i dont want to use the standard name can you help

Comment: The guide I linked you to shows you how to change it.

Comment: I don't see it or how to do it

Comment: @JohnathanMarkSmith can you explain more clearly what you're attempting to do then? Is this still referring to the MongoDB change or application properties file name?

Comment: I am trying to add a file as a resource that I can change the server IP for MonogoDB.... Its something that should be sample but I am new to spring boot... thank

Comment: If that's the case I'd recommend you use the default properties file application.properties to make your change for now. Once you've validated that it works then look to customizing the name of the properties files (e.g. Pass a command line argument like -Dspring.config.name=app-config)

Comment: thats the issue is that Spring Boot is not finding it in the maven build or run

Comment: @JohnathanMarkSmith what if you posted another question with the relevant details such as the log and stack trace?